# activity as AppCompatActivity null, how to fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 override fun setupView() {
        with(Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)) {
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
                (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!,
                this
            )

            bnve.setupWithNavController(this@with)
            addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
                when (destination.id )  {
                    R.id.action_journey -> {
                        (activity as AppCompatActivity).run {
                            supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu)
                            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


                        }
                        bnve.visible()

                    }
                    R.id.action_timeline -> {
                        (activity as AppCompatActivity).run {
                            supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu)
                            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
                        }
                        bnve.visible()
                    }
                    else -> bnve.gone()
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Hello i am newbie developer android , i want make button bottom navigation with navigation drawer but in my crashlytics firebase detected error appcompatactivity  null cannot be cast to non-null, how to fix it? thank you

Comment: Where and when is `setupView()` called? Is this in a Fragment?

Comment: post error logs

Answer (score 0):

You could create a completely new **"Navigation Drawer Activity" or "Bottom Navigation Activity"** and map it with your current activity, so that you could figure out your problem because default activity created by Android Studio has all things set up, we just need to customize as per our requirement.

Make sure your AppTheme should extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` not `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. In BottomNavigation Activity, it uses `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)`, so it is mandatory to use Theme which is extended from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. For instance,

```
    <style name="Theme.MyNavigationApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Use above theme in Activity tag only if you want this theme is only for this Activity. Like :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you want to set above theme for through out entire application then use in application tag.

**Another solution for crash :**
If you have used `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)` in onCreate() method of Activity, then make sure either your activity or application use above mentioned correct theme in manifest.xml file
**OR**
`val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` just after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_test)` in activity.

Comment: i dont know sir how to fix it? i am confuse, sorry i am newbie :O

Comment: i have created navigation drawer activity sir , but i click back on bottom navigation its crash and nulled

Comment: First don't call me sir my friend. My app crashes because I have used wrong theme in my manifest file. Look at updated answer then let me know if your issue still exists.

Comment: ok brother :) thank you very much i will try it :)

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"> i try but crashes sir while open app :(

Comment: Okay, don't loose patience my friend, software is all about patience and don't leave it until you succeed. Looking at your code I guess you are using NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
                (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!,
                this
            )                 inside fragment, right ? I don't know your requirement, but I thing I found that above code should be placed in activity, because all fragments are supposed to share activity's action bar to customize.

Comment: App crash because you are trying to bind action bar of activity with navigation controller, but there is no action bar attached. AppCompatActivity#getSupportActionBar() is called first then action bar will be attached to nav controller. Just go to method definition of NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!,
            this
        )   . Just place cursor on this method and press CTRL+B to see method definition.

Comment: i have clicked sir with ctl+b in NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController( (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!, this )and show pop up no delcaration to go in android studio

Comment: NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController( (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!, this ) inside fragment, yes brother this is inside fragment one activity include 2 fragments with bottom menu button